inner element must either be a resource reference or empty
Helo,
after building my app I get the following error:
/home/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4c63300a97d227157fcc5ffbf3a70b7a/transformed/material-1.11.0/res/values/values.xml:1201:4:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
On line 1201 is:
<item name="row_index_key" type="id"/>

Now I don't know what to do. My app was in Gradle Version 3 and I've updated to 7.4.
I use the following implementations:
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation files('libs/rfc2445-4Mar2011.jar')
implementation files('libs/joda-time-2.9.9.jar')

implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.11.0-beta'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev254-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}


implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android', version: '1.12.0-beta'

implementation group: 'org.dmfs', name: 'lib-recur', version: '0.10'
implementation 'be.billington.calendar.recurrencepicker:library:1.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.eltos:simpledialogfragments:3.8.3'
implementation 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
implementation 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
implementation 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

Anyone an idea?
